# How to build a gallery using colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, colorbox

I've read many times the FAQ but i still don't get any satisfying solution.

I'll explain my situation and my actual problem:

- I have a rollover image, which already has id and class assigned thru a CSS, so i put the "group1" class on the "< a >" tag and it started to work BUT:

  - I want that this image (on click, an href) can open a whole gallery instead of one photo

I noticed that the "colorbox gallery system" works IF i put some hidden code like this:

```
 <div style="display:none">
 <a class="group1" title="Lorenzo2" href="gallery/content/fashion/fash1_2.jpg" ></a>
 <a class="group1" title="Lorenzo3" href="gallery/content/fashion/fash1_3.jpg" ></a>
 <a class="group1" title="Lorenzo4" href="gallery/content/fashion/fash1_4.jpg" ></a>
 </div>
```

This could be a real problem if google's spider catch it and mark it as bannable, however this "solution" can also raise the page's weight a lot I suppose.

How can i open a gallery with colorbox by using only one rolloverimage used as a link(href)?
I'd rather open a whole gallery (for ex. declaring an entire folder filled with images) without being forced to declare in html code that every photo that i got uses "group1" class system used by colorbox.

Really looking forward to an answer,
Regards Lorenzo Martini.

P.s.
I'll leave you a page of my site (still underconstruction) so that you can understand why i need this kind of solution. I want to show a thumbnail which can open a gallery with your script.

http://www.urbanstudiosprato.it/wedding.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, colorbox only works with elements that exist in your document.